# How to use blending in phaserjs

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have searched the whole documents in fact i downloaded them and searched manually. All i found was filter method which allows one to use webgl shadders which you have to write.

What i want is sort of blending as you would see in photoshop light blend for layers etc.

On internet i find examples in pixijs and talk about supporting it in future that happened half year ago. So please anyone who has been following phaserjs and know about filter/blendMode please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

New Phaser 2.0 introduces `blendMode` property for Sprite object. And there is a PIXI enumration for identifying one:

```
PIXI.blendModes = {
    NORMAL:0,
    ADD:1,
    MULTIPLY:2,
    SCREEN:3,
    OVERLAY:4,
    DARKEN:5,
    LIGHTEN:6,
    COLOR_DODGE:7,
    COLOR_BURN:8,
    HARD_LIGHT:9,
    SOFT_LIGHT:10,
    DIFFERENCE:11,
    EXCLUSION:12,
    HUE:13,
    SATURATION:14,
    COLOR:15,
    LUMINOSITY:16
};
```

So, you can simply write

```
sprite.blendMode = PIXI.blendModes.ADD;
```

And here it is.

Comment: can you give me docs link and if i just write: `sprite.blendMode=4` it'd be overlay

Comment: You can find it on PIXI docs (http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/Sprite.html). As far as I know, Phaser docs haven't been updated yet, so there's no blending mode described there. Anyway, the link will not give more information than I posted. Searching the sources also showed that in Canvas mode PIXI can use only NORMAL and ADD.

Comment: can i choose what get affected by blending...like i dont want certain elements to have any effect (bg and some other interactive stuff) but it has to be behind it.

Comment: basically i am asking for 2 different making based on what it is. So if it's bg object then no masking just base color of sprite but if its object that is like house it needs to be blended

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use :

```
spriteName.blendMode =  PIXI.blendModes.TypeOfBlendMode;
```

where:

spriteName is the name of the sprite( let's say player / enemy) and
  TypeOfBlendMode is the type of blend you want to use (which can be  one of the following:
NORMAL, ADD,  MULTIPLY, SCREEN, OVERLAY, DARKEN, LIGHTEN, COLOR_DODGE, COLOR_BURN, HARD_LIGHT, SOFT_LIGHT, DIFFERENCE, EXCLUSION, HUE, SATURATION,  COLOR,  LUMINOSITY ).

Example: let's say the sprite name is player and i want to set the blend mode to MULTIPLY then i will write:

```
player.blendMode = PIXI.blendModes.MULTIPLY;
```